# weird exceptions under android 4.0 with eclipse

Tags: android, warnings

when i using eclipse to develop my android project , the logCat always print these kinds of warnings , but the app runs ok , can any one tell me what has happened.

```
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87): problem reading network stats
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1223)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:771)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:610)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
11-23 18:17:35.802: A/NetworkStats(87):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Drax: Actually, you're not correct there, that is dependent on the kernel version used, in fact, if you're on a older kernel, such as 2.6.35 or thereabouts, you will definitely get this error as the netfilter (part of Linux's iptables netfilter) in Kernel 3 has this feature that is not currently backported to the older kernels.

Comment: I encountered that when porting the AOSP's ICS for the Zte Blade running atop 2.6.35 kernel, and the within the AOSP source, there was repeated iptables calls to xt_qtaguid module, which was eventually backported from kernel 3.0.1.

Answer (score 4):

The 3.0 kernel which ICS is supposed to run on contains a netfilter module: xt_qtaguid

This runs in the background and processes network usage for all PIDs and renders a stat report to the proc fs here:
/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats

You'll notice in the error above:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

This is probably because you probably are missing this module in your kernel.

It can be backported to the 2.6.35 kernel with a little work:
https://github.com/Hashcode/android_device_motorola_solana/tree/ics/modules/netfilter/xt_qtaguid

Answer (score -3):

This is the Error Regarding the network connection framework. since you are using Emulator i guess. and you are not connected to the any internet network, so the framework is trying to get the state of the network and it's not finding anyone and failing to connect

Comment: im also getting this log with the internet connection.

Comment: something related, but not found solution , so u have any solution for this?

Comment: It actually has to do with a missing kernel module NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_QTAGUID