# "unfortunately, myapp has stopped" android simulator error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am getting error "unfortunately, myapp has stopped" when I am trying to open an app which is installed through eclipse on android emulator.here are my files

java file:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        // Initialized SDKs that need to; pass in publisher ids
        Map<SDKAdNetwork, String> publisherIds = new HashMap<SDKAdNetwork, String>();
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.GREYSTRIPE, "486417");
        if (medialetsInitialized == false) {
            publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.MEDIALETS,
                    "PutYourIDHere");
        }
        AdMarvelView.initialize(this, publisherIds, handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // your code
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    try {
        // Initialized SDKs that need to; pass in publisher ids
        Map<SDKAdNetwork, String> publisherIds = new HashMap<SDKAdNetwork, String>();
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.GREYSTRIPE, "486417");
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.MEDIALETS,
                "PutYourIDHere");

        AdMarvelView.pause(this, publisherIds);

        AdMarvelView adMarvelView = (AdMarvelView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        if (adMarvelView != null) {
            adMarvelView.flush();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    try {
        // Initialized SDKs that need to; pass in publisher ids
        Map<SDKAdNetwork, String> publisherIds = new HashMap<SDKAdNetwork, String>();
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.GREYSTRIPE, "486417");
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.MEDIALETS,
                "PutYourIDHere");

        AdMarvelView.resume(this, publisherIds);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    try {
        Map<SDKAdNetwork, String> publisherIds = new HashMap<SDKAdNetwork, String>();
        publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.GREYSTRIPE, "486417");
        if (medialetsInitialized == true) {
            publisherIds.put(SDKAdNetwork.MEDIALETS,
                    "PutYourIDHere");
            medialetsInitialized = false;
        }
        AdMarvelView.uninitialize(this, publisherIds);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // your code
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    handler = new AdMarvelInitializedHandler();

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    final EditText editText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    final EditText editText02 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);

    final EditText editText03 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);

    AdMarvelView adMarvelView = (AdMarvelView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    adMarvelView.setEnableClickRedirect(true);
    adMarvelView.setDisableAnimation(false);
    adMarvelView.setListener(this);
    adMarvelView.setEnableInAppBrowser(true);

    editText01.setText(_partnerId);
    editText02.setText(_siteId);
    editText03.setText(_interstitialSiteId);

    adMarvelInterstitialAds = new AdMarvelInterstitialAds(this, 0,
            0x726D6D, 0x00FF00, 0x000000);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                Map<String, String> targetParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // targetParams.put("GEOLOCATION", "37.686668,-77.4510549");
                // targetParams.put("POSTAL_CODE", "94131");

                final EditText editText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                final EditText editText02 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);

                String partnerId = editText01.getText().toString();
                String siteId = editText02.getText().toString();

                AdMarvelView adMarvelView = (AdMarvelView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
                adMarvelView.requestNewAd(targetParams, partnerId, siteId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                Log.e("admarvel", e.getStackTrace().toString());
            }

        }

    });

    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Map<String, String> targetParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

            targetParams.put("SIZE", "VIDEOPRE");

            final EditText editText01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            final EditText editText03 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText03);

            String partnerId = editText01.getText().toString();
            String interstitialSiteId = editText03.getText().toString();

            AdMarvelInterstitialAds
                    .setListener(AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo.this);
            AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo.this.adMarvelInterstitialAds
                    .requestNewInterstitialAd(AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo.this,
                            targetParams, partnerId, interstitialSiteId);

        }

    });

}

public void onClickAd(AdMarvelView adMarvelView, String clickUrl) {
    if (clickUrl != null) {
        Log.e("admarvel", "ClickUrl: " + clickUrl);
    }

}

public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdMarvelView adMarvelView, int errorCode,
        ErrorReason errorReason) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onFailedToReceiveAd; errorCode: " + errorCode
            + " errorReason: " + errorReason.toString());

}

public void onFailedToReceiveInterstitialAd(SDKAdNetwork sdkAdNetwork,
        String publisherid, int errorCode, ErrorReason errorReason) {

    Log.e("admarvel", "onFailedToReceiveInterstitialAd; errorCode: "
            + errorCode + " errorReason: " + errorReason.toString());

}

public void onReceiveAd(AdMarvelView adMarvelView) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onReceiveAd");
}

public void onRequestAd(AdMarvelView adMarvelView) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onRequestAd");

}

public void onRequestInterstitialAd() {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onRequestInterstitialAd");
}

public void onReceiveInterstitialAd(SDKAdNetwork sdkAdNetwork,
        String publisherid, AdMarvelAd adMarvelAd) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onReceiveInterstitialAd");

    adMarvelInterstitialAds.displayInterstitial(this, sdkAdNetwork,
            publisherid, adMarvelAd);
    if (sdkAdNetwork.equals(SDKAdNetwork.ADMARVEL)) {
        // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    }
}

public void onCloseInterstitialAd() {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onCloseInterstitialAd");
    if (this.adMarvelActivity != null) {
        this.adMarvelActivity.finish();
    } else if (this.adMarvelVideoActivity != null) {
        this.adMarvelVideoActivity.finish();
    }

}

public void onAdmarvelActivityLaunched(AdMarvelActivity a) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onAdmarvelActivityLaunched");
    this.adMarvelActivity = a;

}

public void onAdMarvelVideoActivityLaunched(AdMarvelVideoActivity a) {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onAdmarvelVideoActivityLaunched");
    this.adMarvelVideoActivity = a;

}

public void onExpand() {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onExpand");

}

public void onClose() {
    Log.e("admarvel", "onClose");

}

private class AdMarvelInitializedHandler implements
        AdMarvelInitializeListener {

    public void onInitialized(SDKAdNetwork adnetwork) {

        if (adnetwork.equals(SDKAdNetwork.MEDIALETS)) {
            medialetsInitialized = true;
        }

    }

}

    }
```

and here is the manifest file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.admarvel.androidhelloworlddemo" android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.5">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label=""
    android:debuggable="true"  android:configChanges="orientation" >
    <activity android:name=".AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo"
        android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.admarvel.android.ads.AdMarvelActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.admarvel.android.ads.AdMarvelVideoActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
    </activity>

    <provider android:name="com.admarvel.android.ads.AdMarvelLocalFileContentProvider"
      android:authorities="com.admarvel.androidhelloworlddemo.AdMarvelLocalFileContentProvider" />

    <!--
        ADMARVEL: If your integrating with Admob, please define this activity
    -->

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>

    <!--
        ADMARVEL: If your integrating with Ivdopia, please define this activity
    -->

    <activity android:name="com.vdopia.client.android.VDOActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />

    <!--
        ADMARVEL: If your integrating with Greystripe, please define this
        provider
    -->
    <provider android:name="com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider"
        android:authorities="com.admarvel.androidhelloworlddemo.AdContentProvider"
        android:multiprocess="true" android:exported="false" />

    <!--
        ADMARVEL: If your integrating with Medialets, please define this

    -->
    <service android:name="com.medialets.advertising.AdManagerService" />

    <!--
        ADMARVEL: If your integrating with Greystripe, please define this
        activity
    -->
    <activity android:name="com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdView"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!-- 
        ADMARVEL:  If your integrating with Millennial, please define this
     -->

    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdViewOverlayActivity" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>        
    <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" >
    </activity>

    <!-- 
        ADMARVEL:  If your integrating with Rhythm, please define this
     -->
  <activity android:label="Rhythm Activity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
                        android:name="com.rhythmnewmedia.sdk.RhythmActivity" />
  <activity android:label="Rhythm Video Activity"
                        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
                         android:name="com.rhythmnewmedia.sdk.video.RhythmVideoActivity" />

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"                  
              android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- REQUIRED BY GREYSTRIPE, MEDIALETS, RHYTHM AND MILLENNIAL  -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- REQUIRED BY MEDIALETS -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    </manifest>
```

can someone please help.

EDIT: heres the link to logcat

[logcat file](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=13E3q36C-NuxE39WC9oADv-SdgIeVcrXjSxFMuzIfMOc)

please help!  Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Gates  how do I take logcat logs, sorry I am new to all this.

Comment: If you're in `Java` view in Eclipse, look at the bottom.  There will be a tab called `Logcat`.  Post the red messages in your question.  If you don't see `Logcat`, go to Window -> Show View -> Logcat.

Comment: @Mike Gates    @Sunny Kumar Aditya     first I uninstalled the app from emulator. Then I opened the logcat window in eclipse and I installed the app again on emulator. I didnt get anything in logcat but here are the console messages. ` Installing AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo1.apk...
Success!
Starting activity com.admarvel.androidhelloworlddemo.AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo on device emulator-5554
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.admarvel.androidhelloworlddemo/.AdMarvelHelloWorldDemo }`   these are last 3 msgs

Comment: The console messages are irrelevant.  But you say the Logcat didn't show anything?  In your Logcat view, look to the left at "Saved Filters", then click "All Messages".  Are you getting anything now?  (Note: if you don't see "Saved Filters", click the button to the left of the pause button in the Logcat view to display "Saved Filters" view).  Also note, if you do get Logcat messages, edit your question and post them there, not in a comment.

Comment: @Mike Gates  I got logcat (from command prompt) but they are too big too share here, its going out of characters limit. is there a way to attach a txt file here

Comment: @Mike Gates I Edited my question above to include logcat file link. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's looking for a content provider based on this message, but it can't find it (ClassNotFound)

```
Unable to get provider com.greystripe.android.sdk.AdContentProvider
```

Are you missing a jar in the libs folder?

Comment: I think tha error is gone now but there a diff error  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1`  heres the link to new logcat  [new logcat](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1R8jgfDlBzy8Xdn8hswhzNwRHmIZrhRuIOZ9IAb_VICQ).  Thanks!

Comment: are you using a custom android ROM?  I was able to find something related to your error... check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241068/weird-exceptions-under-android-4-0-with-eclipse

Comment: as far as my limited knowledge goes on these things, I am not using any custom rom. my emulator android version is 4.0.3. To reiterate , I am getting this "unfortunately , the app has stopped" error when I click on the installed app in the emulator. heres the screenshot of that [screenshot](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=13i3NhK2bupxn8NaOF9qko9pRiL6l7aOdE_EKNnmqy8A). thanks for your help!

Comment: I am able to run the app now after some trouble shooting and removing a provider from the manifest file. thanks all!