# Android HTTP-post AsyncHttpClient

Tags: android, http-post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

```
public void postLoginData() {
    AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params1 = new RequestParams();
    params1.put("username", "username");
    params1.put("password", "pass");
    myClient.post(
            "https://68.164.136.217/htdocs/?action=login&returntype=JSON", //"https://68.164.136.217/htdocs/?action=login", //"http://192.168.2.148/htdocs/?action=login&returntype=JSON",
            params1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    System.out.println("login success");
                }
            });
    PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
    myClient.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
    Log.d("Cookies", myCookieStore.getCookies().toString());
}
```

http://pastebin.com/htDhQpKT
Log cat. I do not know why it is giving me this error. I have the internet permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3.0 kernel that runs Ice Cream Sandwich contains a netfilter module named `xt_qtaguid`. This process runs in the background and is responsible for processing the network usage for all PIDs and generating a stats log, located at `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats`. This is probably because you missing this module in your kernel (probably more likely to occur if you are using the emulator... otherwise who knows why).

If you really care enough, it can be backported to the 2.6.35 kernel. Check this [link](https://github.com/Hashcode/android_device_motorola_solana/tree/ics/modules/netfilter/xt_qtaguid) out for more information. You may also want to consult this very similar SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8241068/844882).

Comment: I am not too worried about the compatibility. My manifest says: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" /> and my AVD is set to 2.3.3. Actually I just tried it on this emulator, there seems to be no error, but the code does not enter the on success.

Comment: Ran some more tests, I should not have been using: "https". So it was the compatibility issues. Thank you.