# Android HTTP-post AsyncHttpClient New thread issue

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, http-post

Recently I posted a question about the Android HTTP-post AsyncHttpClient. It is located here: [Android HTTP-post AsyncHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424624/android-http-post-asynchttpclient) The following is the updated method. As you can see this is a boolean method. I have the done variable as a global variable and when the user clicks the Login button I check if postLoginData returned true or false. I need to move on to another activity if true otherwise I show a dialog. But done is being set to true in a new thread and I cannot really have my main thread be waiting because that will cause another error. I'm not sure of what should be my work around. I am hoping someone would post a tutorial that uses AsyncHttpClient to login.

```
public boolean postLoginData(String userid, String password) {
    done = false;
    params1.put("username", "");
    params1.put("password", ""); 
    Log.d("addteq", "Start Get Post"); 
    AsyncHttpClient myClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    myClient.post("http://192.168.2.108/htdocs/?action=login",
            params1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println("login success");
                }
            });
    return done;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach is wrong. The library handles the computations in the background thread:
http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
An asynchronous callback-based Http client for Android built on top of Apache’s HttpClient libraries. All requests are made outside of your app’s main UI thread, but any callback logic will be executed on the same thread as the callback was created using Android’s Handler message passing.

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem, or just additional information?

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Run `postLoginData` inside `doInBackground(..)` and return the boolean. AsyncTask will then take care of it and run `postExecute(..)` in your main thread again where you can start a new activity or show a dialog.