# App can't connect to network with Android ICS

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to port a Phonegap/Cordova app to Android. It works on earlier versions of the SDKs but not on android ICS (SDK 14). I either get `java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`, or the app loads, but can't connect to the internet.

I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` and have checked that their are no duplicate adb or eclipse.exe running. It also cannot connect to the internet on external devices that run android 4+ as well.

My manifest has `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="7" />`

I was pointed in the direction of trace view which when I try to run Network Statistics I get an error "Problem reading xt_qtaguid network statistics fro selected device".

An SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241068/weird-exceptions-under-android-4-0-with-eclipse) indicates there might be an issue with a kernal and suggests backporting, but have no idea how to to do this or if its the right thing to do. My version of Eclipse is Eclipse SDK 3.7.2

Comment: What is exactly the code that you're using to make a connection?

Comment: You could try using this tool to see what is happening with the network connections if traceview can't help. It is called ARO and will show you all the network activity happening when your app is running in the Android emulator. http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312

Comment: Thanks - that looks useful. Regarding the code - at risk of sounding stupid - I have no idea, I don't know Java at all/. What should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since android 4. when somebody trying to do network stuff in UI Thread android with throw a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException . maybe that is a problem?

Comment: Sounds possible - can you explain that to me like I'm five? How do I stop it throwing the exception?

Comment: It's better if i see the code. but do you use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html class for doing network operations? (or which method do you use?)

Comment: Nope never seen that before, not sure how to implement it either. Where in elipse do I add the AsyncTask sub class? I can post code from the project if you tell me which bit is relevant. My ken of java is pretty barren.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html try to understand section 5. TUTORIAL: ASYNCTASK . it's basic in android. And i'm pretty sure that this will solve you problem.