# Android app gives error "BatteryStatsImpl: reading network stats"

Tags: android

Right now I am downloading the images from URL and showing them in List View. I have reffered Lazy List library on github for this.

My application is working fine.But after some time I got following error in logcat:

```
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320): problem reading network stats
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1282)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:831)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPoll(NetworkStatsService.java:799)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$100(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$3.onReceive(NetworkStatsService.java:633)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  ... 10 more
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
03-05 12:18:42.955: A/NetworkStats(12320):  ... 12 more
```

This error come after every 2-3 min.My application is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the problem of your application. I guess that you test your application on a emulator where the support for network statistics was added (API > 12). But emulator relies on an old kernel version (2.6.x), that does not have a module to provide network statistics information. Thus, Android Network Statistics service cannot open file `/proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats` where the statistics gathered by kernel module is collected. Therefore, you obtain these weird errors.

Also, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241068/weird-exceptions-under-android-4-0-with-eclipse) answer.

Comment: Means Yury if I run my app on actual device then it want be create any problem for me...

Comment: Is there be any procedure so that I could remove this error.Please help me my tester forces me to remove this error.

Comment: Try to run the same application on a real device and show the log to your tester and explain that these are not errors of your application. You can also install other application (which uses Internet) and can show that it will also produce the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just changed my emulator to API 28 and the error wasn't there.