# Logcat errors, but the application is working. why?

Tags: android

Hi just want to know what is the problem with this logcat error?

that error always show everytime i run the application, but even it has error the application is perfectly run and working..

just want to know what is the problem with this error..

```
10-06 13:53:16.379        79-96/? A/BatteryStatsImpl﹕ problem reading network stats
java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing idx 1
        at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:300)
        at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:250)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5734)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1652)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1534)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:250)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5734)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1652)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1534)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:269)
            at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:250)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5734)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2457)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1652)
```

thanks,

Joe

Comment: where is your application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15222889/android-app-gives-error-batterystatsimpl-reading-network-stats

Comment: Filter out logs so that only your application logs is shown in it.

Comment: If error are handle like try-catch block then application work even log shown crash.

Comment: The error what you were received may not be error from your app.If you are using Android Studio select your application in Android monitor tab and set option on the right side as "Show only selected application".

Comment: my be some method have try catch which use printStackTrace